# How can i write a query om SPARQL to fetch the details of class and then details of iots subclass?

Tags: sparql, rdf, json-ld

For example in the following json i need to fetch Catalog and Artifacts .I must be able to fetch catalog by artifact and artifact by catalog.While Artifact is not a direct child of Catalog,here is my jsonld.

```
{ "@context": { "ids": "https://w3id.org/idsa/core/", "idsc": "https://w3id.org/idsa/code/" }, "@type": "ids:Root", "@id": "http://component.abc.xyz.domainname.de", "ids:resourceCatalog": [ { "@type": "ids:ResourceCatalog", "@id": "https://w3id.org/idsa/autogen/resourceCatalog/897434ab-8638-4cf5-81da-7e1ea8ccd850", "ids:offeredResource": [ { "@type": "ids:Resource", "@id": "https://w3id.org/idsa/autogen/resource/ffcc840c-f7a9-4465-aee7-7d9f3ce39d27", "ids:representation": [ { "@type": "ids:Representation", "@id": "https://w3id.org/idsa/autogen/representation/3ef065fd-c985-4d5a-af8f-59f875c88931", "ids:instance": [ { "@type": "ids:Artifact", "@id": "http://component.abc.xyz.domainname.de/artifact/json-jsonld.txt", "ids:fileName": "json-jsonld.txt", "ids:creationDate": { "@value": "2020-12-17T18:27:44.158+01:00", "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTimeStamp" }, "ids:byteSize": 694 } ] } ] }, { "@type": "ids:Resource", "@id": "https://w3id.org/idsa/autogen/resource/cc011e72-c1e3-4754-94b2-30a45ca967a3", "ids:representation": [ { "@type": "ids:Representation", "@id": "https://w3id.org/idsa/autogen/representation/343c0a82-e2d9-4453-a16b-93c23d172733", "ids:instance": [ { "@type": "ids:Artifact", "@id": "http://component.abc.xyz.domainname.de/artifact/demoSample-desc.jsonId", "ids:fileName": "demoSample-desc.jsonId", "ids:creationDate": { "@value": "2020-11-05T12:44:00.788+01:00", "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTimeStamp" }, "ids:byteSize": 1338 } ] }]}]}]}
```

Comment: load the data and use a SPARQL query then.

Comment: Thats my Quesion here is the subclass query i tried .PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX ids: <https://w3id.org/idsa/core/>

 

SELECT ?artifact WHERE {?artifacts  rdfs:subClassOf ids:ResourceCatalog}

Comment: your data does **not** contain any subclass triples ... it's `rdf:type` resp. its shortcut you have to use: `{ ?artifacts a ids:ResourceCatalog }`

Comment: I used  subClassOf to get the subclass od resource catalog ,but i think there are some other subclasses in between ResourceCatalog and Artifact.Artifacts are inside Representation Class and Respresentation is Inside a resource and Resourece is contained inside offered resources which is contained inside Resource Catalog

Comment: not sure what you're saying ... your dataset does **not** contain any `rdfs:subClassOf` triple. You can only query for data that is inside the data you loaded into your SPARQL engine. So what is the problem now? Either you add the `rdfs:subClassOf` triples to your dataset/triple store or you have to use another query. Tehre is no magic happening under the hood, SPARQL tried to match the patterns of your query with the data

Comment: The problem is i dont know how to fetch child of child elements ,I need a query for that

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. You have data shown, ok. But this daata doesn't contain `rdfs:subClassOf` statements. So what should the query return here? Not sure if you understand the point, but nobody here can help you without seeing the whole given data and the expected result. "fetch child of a child" ... what does this mean? Use URIs instead of cryptic terms like "child".

Comment: Okay this is the json ld data and  i need to query this data ,my problem is simple i need a QUERY SYNTAX FOR......Fetching artifacts when i am given a resourcecatalog Id .I hopw i am somewhat clear now.